# Back div blocks scrolling for frontmost div

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'd like to get non-scrolling background div on page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="back"/>
    <div class="front">
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus turpis tortor, semper id suscipit vel, bibendum eu magna. Nullam a libero nisi. Fusce eget elementum augue. Ut tellus leo, dignissim varius finibus a, aliquet ut turpis. Proin non elit luctus, maximus nunc ac, auctor elit. Nullam erat ante, faucibus ac viverra eget, finibus nec ipsum. Vivamus sit amet purus accumsan justo finibus rutrum eu nec nunc.</p>
      <p>Suspendisse eros lorem, luctus vitae volutpat ultricies, egestas et risus. Morbi fermentum iaculis nunc, ac tincidunt elit tristique sed. Aenean efficitur velit elit, vitae efficitur ex lobortis non. Etiam in orci ut libero lobortis laoreet. Suspendisse efficitur et sem non bibendum. Nam iaculis, mi in pharetra auctor, diam tellus commodo eros, eget volutpat ipsum enim vitae justo. Sed non ullamcorper odio, ac euismod ligula. Proin euismod eleifend convallis. Vivamus maximus accumsan dignissim. Morbi interdum magna sit amet tempor lacinia. Vivamus nec mi ligula. Donec tortor ex, commodo a est sit amet, volutpat gravida risus. Mauris vitae malesuada est. Curabitur blandit posuere ligula sit amet feugiat. Sed est tellus, cursus eget laoreet et, imperdiet eget dui. Donec facilisis, leo at mollis maximus, sapien purus lacinia mauris, ut fringilla turpis nibh finibus nunc.</p>
      <p>Maecenas eget lorem posuere, tincidunt massa sit amet, vehicula diam. Nunc vel consequat nulla. Etiam volutpat volutpat fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. In mattis ex non ex iaculis, eu gravida nulla ultrices. Curabitur ut sem purus. Donec quis tempor lorem, faucibus condimentum eros. Donec massa dui, euismod non tincidunt sed, tempor id nisl. Pellentesque varius mollis nibh.</p>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My style.css looks like:

```
.back {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: lightblue;
  }
  .front {
    position: relative;
  }
```

What I expect - my long text scrolled over lightblue background (first div).

Whit I've seen - scrolling locked, I see just on-screen portion of long-text. So, div.back seems to be at top of z-index stack, when I expect opposite.

Why it's happen?

Comment: [validate](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) your HTML.

Comment: @Alohci: yes, you're right. Reason was in non-valid html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Alohci:

`<div class="back"/>` is invalid.

Correct is `<div class="back"></div>`